# TCPDF- php variables inside writeHTML()

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to put 3 different html string into PDF using TCPDF

I have 3 variables containing html string.

But below code writes only $var3 's value to pdf.

How to display all 3 variable's value to pdf ?

```
$var1= "<html> --- </html>";
$var2= "<html> --- </html>";
$var3= "<html> --- </html>";

$html = $va1.''.$var2.''.$var3;

$pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, true, false, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

is there a need to use html tags in each variable ? Otherwise I'd try something like:

```
 $html = '$var1 html content';
 $html .= '$var2 html content';
 $html .= '$var3 html content';

 $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

**Simple Example #1**

```
$html = '<h1>Some text</h1>
         <table>
         <tbody>';
$html .= '<tr><td>A Row</td></tr>';
$html .= '</tbody>
          </table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, true, false, '');
```

**A bit less simple Example #2**

```
$html = '<h1>Some text</h1>
         <table>
         <tbody>';
for($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++)
{
  $html .= '<tr>
            <td>A Row</td>
            <td>A Row</td>
            <td>A Row</td>
            <td>A Row</td>
            </tr>';
}
$html .= '</tbody>
          </table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, true, false, '');
```

P.S.
There is no need to use the html tags when you use the writeHTML class.